# Laravel updating polymorphic models

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, eloquent

I have two models with a polymorphic relationship, one called *Article* the other one *Image*. I am posting an array of Image id's in order to update the dataset. As far as I can tell `Eloquent` doesn't have a *sync()* method for polymorphic relationships, *sync()* can be used when working with *Pivot* tables.

```
$article = new Article();

foreach (Input::file('images') as $file) {
   $image = new Image();
   $image->file_name = $file-> getClientOriginalName();
   $article->images()->save($image);
}
```

Stub code for updating:

```
$article = Article::findOrFail($id);
$ids = Input::get('images'); // array('1', '3', ...);
$article_image_ids = $article->images()->lists('id'); // array('1','2','3', …);
```

How do I save the posted ID's and make sure the article images data gets updated?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused what you are looking for, but you could do something like this to sync.

```
// This will take care of the deletion of images already in place for said article.
Image::where('imageable_type', 'Article')->where('imageable_id', $article_id)->delete();

// This will insert the desired records back
$article = Article::find($article_id)
foreach($ids as $image_id) {
    $image = Image::find($image_id):
    $article->images()->save($image);
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution which can do a bulk update. I don't want to both delete and create these entries within a foreach loop

Comment: I realized the sync() method does work for this purpose as well. When storing the entries an attach method can be used and when updating the sync() does the trick

Comment: Please post a code example as an answer since it seems you have answered your own question.